# If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{f_n}$ diverges, does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1+f_n}$ also diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I have been trying to solve the following problem:
Given $f(n): \mathbb{N} \rightarrow (0,\infty)$. If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{f_n}$ diverges, does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1+f_n}$ also diverge?

I suspect that this is true, but I can't find a way of proofing this formally. The problem is that we don't know any other characteristics about $f_n$ other than that it is a positive function.

It might be the case that this is not true, but it would be nice in that case to see an example.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Try writing $\frac{1}{1+f_n}=\frac{\frac{1}{f_n}}{1+\frac{1}{f_n}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\sum \frac{1}{1+f_{n}} < \infty$

Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{1+f_{n}} = 0$

So $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1 + f_{n} = \infty$, thus $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_{n} = \infty$

Then there's exist $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f_{n} > 1$ for all $n>N$

Then $\infty > \sum_{n = N+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 + f_{n}} \geq \sum_{n = N+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{f_{n} + f_{n}} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n = N+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{f_{n}} = \infty$

That is a contradiction.

Then diverges too.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $t \ge 1$ we have ${1 \over t} \le 2 { 1 \over t+t} \le {2 \over 1+t}$.
In particular, if $f_n \ge 1$ we have ${1 \over f_n} \le 2 {1 \over 1+f_n}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_{n}$ DNE, then so also $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{1 + f_{n}}$, and so the series diverges.

If $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_{n} = 0$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{1 + f_{n}} = 1$, and so the series diverges.

Otherwise, use the Limit Comparison Test with both of the series you have indicated, and you should be able to conclude divergence for these cases as the limit of the resulting quotient will be $1$.

Comment: I considered the Limit Comparison Test, but I disregarded it, since we don't know anything regarding $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n$.

Comment: The LCT gives you what you are looking for provided that $\lim f_{n} \neq 0$ or D.N.E. Now, if $\lim f_{n}$ DNE, what does that say about the series you're interested in. Finally, if $\lim f_{n} = 0$, what does that tell you about the limit of $\frac{1}{1 + f_{n}},$ and so, what can you conclude from there? It's a good problem!